# Node.js syntax error when I create an index.js file via echo in the terminal

Tags: node.js, terminal

This is mostly a curiosity, but recently when creating a node.js app I experimented with creating my main index.js file in the terminal via the following statement: `echo $null >> index.js`. Doing so successfully created the file, but when I tried starting the server with `node index.js`, I got `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`. I don't get this error if I create the new file using my IDE. I checked for whitespace characters, but didn't see anything out of the ordinary. Any thoughts why this isn't working? I'm running Windows. Below is my code and the error:

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("I'm listening");
});
```

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

Comment: `echo $null >> index.js` will record unprintable symbol to the file 0x0A.
Try `echo $null | hexdump`
EDIT: didn't notice that you use Windows, try to open index.js via any hex-viewer, you don't have `hexdump`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the insight!